# gitworkflows' 'next' branch

Tags: git, workflow

I am trying to adopt something similar to gitworkflows(7).

The documentation says that the 'next' branch only is regenerated after a release cycle. Why can't it be regenerated every time there is a change in a topic branch, just like the 'pu' branch? Nobody should base their work on this branch anyway, should they?.

Thanks

Comment: It feels like you are referencing something, but you don't explain what it is.  Can you provide a link to gitworkflows?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark: He means https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html (which is more or less a description of what the Git folks use when maintaining Git itself). This is not the only model for releases, and I personally do not know of anyone else who uses it. I'd suggest also looking at http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/05/git-workflows-that-work.html for instance.